# How to extract How uncompress .tar.lrz file in centos 8?

Tags: linux, centos, compression, zip, tar

I have `.tar.lrz` file in mac which I have to decompress.

I am trying decomprees file from https://github.com/lin-tan/CoCoNut-Artifact/releases/tag/training_data_1.0.0

I already tried:

```
yum install lrzip
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.5 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.10-rpms                                                                                                                                            | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
No package lrzip available.
```

Comment: lrzip seems to be a solution looking for a problem, maybe contact the supplier of the files and ask them to use something more mainstream like LZMA

Comment: Try installing packages `lrunzip` or `lrzuntar`.

Comment: On opensuse, your distro may vary, but it has `patool` which says it supports that compression, Not used it, just read the package descrption.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 8 is EOL. You should look into upgrading to a different distribution ASAP.

---

If packages for some software are not available for your distribution, you can still build the software yourself. For small programs like *lrzip*, this should be relatively easy, too.

According to the [README file](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip#lrzip-buildinstall-guide) you need the following libraries/compilers/tools:

- gcc
- bash or zsh
- pthreads
- tar
- libc
- libm
- libz-dev
- libbz2-dev
- liblzo2-dev
- liblz4-dev
- coreutils
- Optional nasm
- glibc or comparable libc

Distributions often have a *build-essential* (or similar) meta-package that installs all the usual stuff (Make, GCC, glibc-dev, …) for compiling software.

You can get the source code either using Git or as a snapshot from the project’s releases page.

If everything is set, building should then be as easy as:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j 4 # where 4 is your CPU/core count
```

If it worked, you can install it:

```
sudo make install
```

By default (no special `./configure` arguments), the binaries will end up in `/usr/local/bin`, which *may* not be in `$PATH`.

Alternatively, you can also run it directly from the source directory.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a Unix system, to uncompress `*.Z` or `*.tar.Z` files, at the shell prompt, enter:

```bash
  uncompress *.Z
```

Use the `ls` command to check the resulting files. If uncompress creates a `.tar` file, you must extract the files by entering:

```bash
  tar -xvf *.tar
```

Alternatively, to do this in one step and avoid creating the intermediate `*.tar` file, enter:

```bash
  zcat *.Z | tar -xvf -
```

For more information, refer to the online manual by entering:

```bash
  man tar
  man uncompress
  man zcat
```

Comment: Not sure how this is related to the question. OP has _.lrz_ files.